# Memcache memory over allocation

Tags: memory, memcached

Is it possible to over allocate memory to Memcache in such a manner it adversely impacts get/set performance?

I've read most all Memcache operations are O(1) so I would think that the answer is no, but I am not an expert on Memcache.

For example, 4GB is currently allocated and full with 12.5% wasted space and 8 evictions happening a second.  Multiple web site use this dedicated Memcache server.  So, would doubling, tripling, etc... the memory hurt the system as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not possible to over allocate memory to memcached. One exception here is if you allocate more memory than you actually have available and it causes some of the memcached address space to be swapped out to disk. This could happen if you have a lot of applications running on a machine that all use a lot of memory.

Comment: In Varnish, there is a 1k object overhead outside of the allocated memory.  Are you aware of anything similar in Memcache?  i.e. Does it use internal data structures that do not count towards the total allocated memory?

Comment: Each item has a small amount of meta data associated to it which is only to hold the expiration time (8 Bytes). As far as I know there is nothing else stored with each key.